# Install postgres without apt-get

Tags: linux, debian, root, postgresql

I have access to a machine on a scientific hpc, and I'm setting up an environemnt to create a web application, made up basically of [TOMCAT](http://tomcat.apache.org/) and [postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/).
I cannot use another web server.

The OS is linux with Debian (squeeze) and I don't have *root* access to the machine.

After googling a bit around, I only found method which required root access to the machine for installing postgresql (apt-get ....).

Is it possible to install postgresql in a local directory where I have full permissions? Or Does postgresql necessarily requires root access to be installed? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [PostgreSQL can be installed without being root](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-install.html), although the [installation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/installation.html) has to be done manually, as you cannot use the package manager of your distribution.

Answer (score 6):

Two ways:

- [compile from source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/installation.html); or
- [Download EnterpriseDB's pre-compiled platform-independent-ish binaries](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload) then `initdb` yourself and start the server with `pg_ctl`.

Comment: can confirm the second approach worked without a problem (and was probably easier than compiling from source)

Comment: Maybe things have changed since then, but now the EnterpriseDB Linux download requires root privileges.

Comment: @mlv The *installer* does. The binary zip does not.

Comment: The compile from source may requires to apt-get some package for compilation which requires root.
Download from https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries works great on my ubuntu.

Just download, unpack, then ready to go

Init database
./initdb -D /data

Run postgres
./bin/postgres -D /data

Create database
./bin/createdb mydb

Connect with psql
./bin/psql mydb

Ref. https://www.golery.com/pencil/vU

Answer (score 1):

This would have saved me a lot of time, download the binary, put it in a file share or cloud and then:

**Linux:**

```
aws s3 cp 's3://yourAwsBucket/postgresql-9.6.21-1-linux-x64-binaries.tar.gz' .
tar xvzf postgresql-9.6.21-1-linux-x64-binaries.tar.gz
cd pgsql/bin
psql -c 'Select version();' "postgresql://<user>:<password>@<dbendpoint>/<dbName>"
```

or if you get a **no such file or directory 'psql'** using subprocess, try putting **bash** as the first argument:

```
print(subprocess.run(['bash','psql','-c','Select version();','postgresql://<user>:<password>@<dbendpoint>/<dbName>'],shell=isWindows, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('ascii'))
```

**Windows:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854798/how-do-i-install-just-the-client-tools-for-postgresql-on-windows