# Installing TOMCAT on Debian without apt-get

Tags: debian, root, apt-get, tomcat

I have access to a machine on a scientific hpc, and I'm setting up an environemnt to create a web application, made up basically of TOMCAT and postgresql. I cannot use another web server.

The OS is linux with Debian (squeeze) and I don't have root access to the machine.

After googling a bit around, I only found methods which required root access to the machine for installing TOMCAT (apt-get ....).

Is it possible to install TOMCAT in a local directory where I have full permissions? Or Does it necessarily requires root access to be installed? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement for tomcat to be run as a different user, you can just download a package from e.g. [Tomcat 7 Downloads](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi), unpack and use.

Of course, if you want to bind to a privileged port you need permissions for it.

Answer (score 1):

I general, when you don't have root access, you need to compile from source. This is usually done with the following steps:

1. Download the package

   ```
   wget http://www.example.com/tomcat.tgz
   ```
2. Extract it, this should create a directory with the name of the package.

   ```
   tar xvzf tomcat.tgz
   ```
3. Move into the newly created directory and run the provided `configure` script, giving it your `$HOME` as the install prefix

   ```
   cd tomcat
   ./configure --prefix=$HOME
   ```
4. Compile ad install

   ```
   make && make install
   ```

That will install the program's files in subdirectories of your `$HOME`, for example `$HOME/bin`, `$HOME/lib` etc. Now, whether this will work for something as large/complex as a web server I cannot tell you, but it would surprise me if it does. While this approach may well install it, getting access to it and having it function correctly as a web server is probably going to be more complex. If you get this far, post another questions with any new issues you face. Good luck!

Comment: unfortunately the offical tomcat installation guides points out that it has to be installed with another procedure. Check here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/building.html#Introduction
The method you show is general and usually works for other src packages (it worked for me here http://superuser.com/questions/708583/install-postgres-without-apt-get), but not in this case... maybe you want to updare your answer...